# Shipping costs remove in cart grand total in Magento 1.9

Tags: cart, magento-1.9, checkout

I have add product in cart after that I have checkout page, now in checkout page I will fill the all details also select shipping method but not proceed order.

After that I have going on cart then my grand total showing with shipping cost so I have to remove this shipping cost in my cart grand total because customer can confusion how that total will increase.

So I will only show product total with text in cart if I am select shipping method they can't be display in cart only show at checkout time.

Is this possible in Magento 1.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Create an observer in checkout_cart_save_before

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_save_before>
            <observers>
            <your_module_shipping_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Your_Module/observer</class>
                <method>setShipping</method>
            </your_module_shipping_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_save_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

And in your observer try this

```
public function setShipping($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $cart = $event->getCart();
    $shippingaddress = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingaddress->setShippingMethod('')->save();
    return;
}
```